# How to do something when a CheckBox is unchecked

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox

I want a select all `CheckBox` which when `Checked`, checks all other `CheckBoxes` and when `Unchecked`, unchecks the others. I have written this code:

```
private void all_CheckedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (all.IsChecked == true)//this is working
    {
        issue.IsChecked = true;
        summary.IsChecked = true;
        type.IsChecked = true;
        status.IsChecked = true;
        label.IsChecked = true;
        components.IsChecked = true;
        empty.IsChecked = true;
        reporter.IsChecked = true;
        requester.IsChecked = true;
        team.IsChecked = true;
        assignee.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else if (all.IsChecked == false)//this is not doing anything
    {
        issue.IsChecked = false;
        summary.IsChecked = false;
        type.IsChecked = false;
        //same for other checkboxes
    }
}
```

when I debug it I see that the event takes places when I check the `CheckBox` but nothing happens when I uncheck it. Someone, please suggest me how to do this in case I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Why there is `else if (..)` else is enough na? since `IsChecked` is a boolean property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF's `CheckBox` you have not the `Changed` event. You have used the `Checked` event so you have to specify the `Unchecked` also and attach the same handler to both events. So your XAML code should be like this:

```
<CheckBox Name="all" Checked="All_OnChecked" Unchecked="All_OnChecked"></CheckBox>
```

However I strongly recommend that you use [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) for this purposes.

Answer (score 3):

This is assuming you already have the checkboxes in the XAML file.

Be sure to add the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events to the `SelectAll` checkbox in the XAML file.

Then, populate what you want each event to do. In your case, you want the `Checked` event to check all the other checkboxes and the `Unchecked` event to do the opposite.

Try this...

#### MainPage.xaml.cs file

```
private void SelectAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   issue.IsChecked = true;
   // Do the rest for all other checkboxes you want to check
}

private void SelectAll_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    issue.IsChecked = false;
   // Do the rest for all other checkboxes you want to uncheck
}
```

#### MainPage.xaml file

```
<CheckBox x:Name="SelectAll" Content="Select All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Checked="SelectAll_Checked" 
    Unchecked="SelectAll_Unchecked" />
<!-- Other checkboxes ... -->
```

Check out [my Gist link](https://gist.github.com/sometowngeek/0777e75d148bd9b80d8cc972d40856eb) for this example.

Comment: I am not setting it. But thanks @S.Akbari's answer in working.

Comment: @komalThawani No worries. He (or she) pointed it out before I had a chance to finish my answer. If his or her answer works, then that's great! :)

Comment: I had figured out the first part, just hadn't thought I needed to tie into XAML somehow. Great work Cheers.